# Div Backgrounds That Overlap At The Corner

Tags: html, css

There are several separate background images, displayed top to bottom. Is it possible to make them overlap slightly and clip a transparent triangular area in the bottom-right corner revealing the image below?

Is this possible with CSS?

Here is the desired look:

[image: Example]

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: My guess is that this was done in `Photoshop` but I can't say for certain it is not possible in `CSS`.

Comment: I find the close votes interesting... this may not be the best question, but it's pretty clear and not overly broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is very possible with CSS.

Here is a technique using a rotated div and `:before` pseudo element. This looks like a long explanation, but the basic principal is pretty straight forward once you start poking around.

**Compatibility:** [IE9 + and all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) — The `transform` property in IE9 requires the `-ms-` prefix and Safari requires the `-webkit-` prefix. They should be placed *before* the unprefixed property.

### The wrapper

The wrapper is used to clip the slanted corners of each div.

- Provide a suitable max and min width
- Clip its children with `overflow: hidden`

### The div

The div is used to create the slant by clipping its childrens bottom right corner.

- Rotate with `transform: rotate()`
- Clip its children with `overflow: hidden`
- Blow the width out with `width: 200%` so that the corners are clipped by the wrapper
- Move every div (except the first div) up with a negative margin
- Change the z-order with `z-index` so that each div is overlapped by the div before it

### The `:before` pseudo element

The `:before` provides the actual background image without any extra markup.

- Counter the div parents rotation by the same number of degrees
- Provide the background image
- Shift as needed with `transform-origin`

The straight edge is provided by the bottom edge of the image and the corner is cut off by the parent. The image must be quite large to overlap the width of its parent.

### Full Example

[Example with prefixes.](http://jsbin.com/kodekifedi/1/edit?css,output)

```css
.wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  min-width: 660px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #EEE;
}
.wrap > div {
  transform: rotate(-15deg);
  height: 700px;
  width: 200%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-origin: 0 90%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
.wrap > div:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-1500-1000-2.jpg) no-repeat;
  transform: rotate(15deg);
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 30% 0;
}
.wrap > div:nth-child(n+2) {
  margin-top: -140px;
}
.wrap > div:nth-child(2):before {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-1500-1000-10.jpg);
}
.wrap > div:nth-child(3):before {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-1500-1000-3.jpg);
}
.wrap > div:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 9;
}
.wrap > div:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 8;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  The Code snippet doesn't work in safari, but it looks great in Chrome.

Comment: @turkeyhundt - Safari [needs the `-webkit-` prefix for the transforms](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) which should be placed *before* the standard property -- [like this example (working in Safari)](http://jsbin.com/zekofu/2/edit?css,output)